# Google Authentication Asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-authentication

I'm getting the below error when I try to login using Google on my web app.
It works fine when using localhost

> This pelusoftcamerawebapp.azurewebsites.net page can’t be found No web
>   page was found for the web address:
>   https://pelusoftcamerawebapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-google?state=CfDJ8BRnSyuVZrdLjm6frrOu1DBgXqvK5dey3eI632SEKrS7vg........

goole login code:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("google-login")]
        public IActionResult GoogleLogin(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            var authProperties = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationProperties
            {
                RedirectUri = string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) ? "account/profile" : returnUrl,
                IsPersistent = true
            };

            return Challenge(authProperties, new string[] { "google" });
        }
```

I have added  `pelusoftcamerawebapp.azurewebsites.net` to the google console domain verification

do you have any idea?

Comment: https://pelusoftcamerawebapp.azurewebsites.net/signin-google returns a 404. The URL just doesn't exist. Did you forget to deploy it or something?

Comment: the app is deployed, you can access it

Comment: Yes I can see that, but the `/signin-google` URL (as mentioned in the error message) doesn't exist, that's my point. What I meant was maybe you didn't deploy a version which includes functionality to make that bit work.

Comment: that's part of the google authentication. It doesn't exist on localhost neighter but it will be intercepted by google handler

Comment: then I would assume presumably the google handler code is either not working or not deployed correctly. Obviously without code or config info I'm shooting in the dark a bit. Possibly the answer below does have some relevance, somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Since Google has shutdown **Google Plus** so Google Plus based authentication mechanism has been changed and it has also effected the existing Google authentication in ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core.

Microsoft has updated the Google authentication library for both ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core.

Here is the more details: [Google+ based auth deprecation and replacement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/333)

Comment: that may all be true but it doesn't explain why there's an error only in the deployed environment and not in localhost. If the google side had been updated then I'd expect OP's code not to work in any environment, don't you think? Also where does the question mention Google Plus?

Comment: @ADyson Yes! You are correct. `Also where does the question mention Google Plus?`- In ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core google authentication was actually based on Google Plus and now It has changed as Google plus has been shut down.